# Solving errors in view transitions (storyboards)

Tags: ios, objective-c, view, uistoryboard

I'm developing an application that works with 2 different views. Today I noticed that every time I step from view 1 to view 2 the app creates a new view.
And when I return to the previous view it simply creates a new instance of view1, ie it creates a new view in memory. (and keep the previous)

I would like to use the same view without creating a new instance (a new view in memory) each time the user passes a view to another.

I would like transit between just the 2 views that I created.

Note: I'm using the iOS 6 with Storyboard and ARC. And the transition is made by a tap gesture recognizer. Once I tap the view it goes to the next view using a modal transition.

Comment: It's too abstract before we can give suggestions. Please post your page flow / storyboard .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you go from view controller 1 to view controller 2 as a modal (presented) view controller, you use a modal segue. This will indeed create a new instance of view controller 2. When you go back, in iOS 6, you must use an *unwind* segue to the first view controller. This will cause the view controller 2 to go out of existence, and it will use the existing view controller 1, not create a new view controller 1.

Here's my explanation of unwind segues.

http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch19.html#_unwind_segues

(Either that, or don't use a segue at all; just call `dismissViewController` yourself, as we did in iOS 5 before unwind segues existed. Or don't use a storyboard in the first place; they really aren't necessary. Here's my explanation of presented ["modal"] view controllers: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch19.html#_presented_view_controller)